# Is there a single C++ IDE packed with necessary scientific libraries for computing purpose?

Tags: parallel-computing, c++, hpc, libraries, visualization

I am basically looking for a good open source C++ IDE with scientific and visualization libraries built in. Can any one suggest few projects?

Comment: This doesn't exist. IDEs and scientific libraries are entirely separate projects. You can of course find Linux distributions that package both, but the scientific libraries are separate packages from the IDE packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Ceemple http://www.ceemple.com. It a IDE with some scientific computing package.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! If you could provide a longer explanation to accompany your link, that would be great!